# Configuring vsftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I am trying to configure an FTP server using `vsftpd` on my CentOS server.

I have installed the FTP server using `yum install vsftpd` and followed: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-fedora-centos-vsftpd-installation.html to configure the server.

I have created a user, but when I try to connect via Filezilla, I get:

```
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/username
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Looking the vsftpd log i get:

Thu Sep  1 11:41:19 2011 [pid 8535] CONNECT: Client "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
Thu Sep  1 11:41:19 2011 [pid 8534] [username] OK LOGIN: Client "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

It seems to disconnect me from the server.

I can also logon via SFTP in Filezilla.

Thanks

UPDATED:

```
getsebool -a | grep ftp

allow_ftpd_anon_write --> off
allow_ftpd_full_access --> off
allow_ftpd_use_cifs --> off
allow_ftpd_use_nfs --> off
ftp_home_dir --> off
ftpd_connect_db --> off 
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
sftpd_anon_write --> off
sftpd_enable_homedirs --> off
sftpd_full_access --> off
sftpd_write_ssh_home --> off
tftp_anon_write --> off
```

Comment: What is the output of `getsebool -a | grep ftp`?

Comment: Updated my question with the outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ftp_home_dir --> off
```

`setsebool ftp_home_dir on` and try again.

Comment: You need to set the `P` option in as `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir` on if you need the change to be persistent after reboot.